# press CommandButton twice for performing action

Tags: visualforce

I am facing a problem with the 'Create' CommandButton, where I need to press twice to complete the action. While choosing the first RadioButton option i.e 'Fixed', it is working fine, but when I choose the second option i.e 'Variable', it refreshes the page once then I have to press the button again to complete the action.

Here is the code of my VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="RuleController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<title>Create Simple Rule</title>
<c:SCTHeader includeHeader="true"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.angular_js}" />
    
    
     <script>
function show(t)
{
    
    if ( t == 'Fixed' ){
    
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId}').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId1}').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.fixId}').disabled = false;  
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId}').value=" ";
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId1}').value=" "; 
       
    }
    else if ( t == 'Variable' ){
    
     document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId}').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.varId1}').disabled = false;
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.fixId}').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm1.pb.fixId}').value=" "; 
    
    }     
}
  </script>
   <script>
  function MyjavaFunction(ReceiveInputID){ 
    var inputValue = document.getElementById(ReceiveInputID).value; 
         if(inputValue == ''){
            alert('Please enter the rule name');
         } 
         
   }
  </script>  

    <apex:form id="frm1"> 

        <div align="center">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Compensation Rule Details" id="pb">
                <table class="bgcborder">
                    <tbody class="responstable">

                    <tr>
                        <th><b>Compensation:</b></th>
                        <td><table><tr>
                                    <td><apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" value="{!rule.CompensationType__c}" onchange="show(this.value);" >
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Fixed" itemValue="Fixed"></apex:selectOption>
                                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Variable" itemValue="Variable"></apex:selectOption>
                                        </apex:selectRadio></td>
                                   <td>
                                   <apex:inputText size="8" value="{!rule.fixedComp_Value__c}"  id="fixId" html-placeholder="0"/><br/><br/>
                                   Apply Formula&nbsp;<apex:inputText value="{!rule.compensation_Formula__c}" id="varId"  /><br/><br/>
                                   Parameters <apex:inputText value="{!rule.compensation_Parameters__c}" id="varId1"  /><br/>
                                   (Use RULE_OUTPUT or MIN_REQUIREMENT for the result of the rule evaluation.)</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr> 


                </tbody></table><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Create" action="{!create}" onclick="MyjavaFunction('{!$Component.inptID}')"/>
                    
                    
                    &nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!a}" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
    
<c:SCTFooter includeFooter="true"/>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the controller class method for the page:

```
    
     public PageReference create()
    { 
        bool2=false;
        String ruleName = rule.ruleName__c;
        
        if(rSimple.Minimum_Requirement__c != '' && rSimple.Minimum_Requirement_Param__c != null)
        {
            bool2=true;
            PageReference  pageReff = new PageReference('/apex/CreateSimpleRule');
            return pageReff;
        }else
        if(rSimple.calculation_Mode__c == '' || rSimple.calculation_Mode__c == null)
        {
        bool1=true;
        PageReference  pageReff = new PageReference('/apex/CreateSimpleRule');
        return pageReff;
        }
        else{
       if(rule.ruleName__c == '' || rule.ruleName__c == null)
        {
        return page.CreateSimpleRule;
        }
        
        insert rule;
        Rule__c insertedRule = [select Rule__c.ID from Rule__c where Rule__c.ruleName__c = :ruleName];
        rSimple.Rule_Id__c = insertedRule.ID;
        insert rSimple;
        for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++)
        {
            lstParameter.add(lstInner[j].rParameter);
        } 
        List<RuleParameter__c> parameters  = new List<RuleParameter__c>();
        Iterator<RuleParameter__c> iter = lstParameter.iterator();
       integer detailsrl=0;
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            RuleParameter__c rp = (RuleParameter__c)iter.next();
            RuleParameter__c rp1 = new RuleParameter__c();
            if(rp.parameterName__c != null & rp.parameterValue__c !=null){
            rp1.parameterName__c = rp.parameterName__c;
            rp1.parameterValue__c = rp.parameterValue__c;
            rp1.detailSrl__c = detailsrl;
            rp1.rule_Id__c = insertedRule.Id;
            detailsrl++;
            parameters.add(rp1);
        }
        }
        insert parameters;
        String ruleId = insertedRule.Id;
        Rule_Simple__c insertedSimpleRule = [select Rule_Simple__c.ID ,Rule_Simple__c.Name from Rule_Simple__c where Rule_Simple__c.Rule_Id__c = :ruleId];
       
      
      //******************for aggregate function value saved into the simple rule table*************************

    aggregateFunction__c agg;
       
    
       agg=[select ID, aggregateFunction__c.functionName__c from aggregateFunction__c where functionName__c=:theagree];
       
       rSimple.Rule_Id__c = insertedRule.Id;
       
      
       rSimple.aggregateFunctions_Id__c= agg.ID;
        upsert rSimple;
            

            //for creation of simp qualifying clause
            integer detailsrl2=0;
             for(InnerSimpClass i:sInner){
                ConditionList__c scon;
                FieldList__c sfield;
                functionList__c sfunc; 
                                
                if(i.simpcond != null)
                    scon=[select ID, ConditionList__c.ConditionValue__c from ConditionList__c where ConditionValue__c=:i.simpcond];
                if(i.simpfield != null)
                    sfield=[select ID, FieldList__c.DisplayName__c from FieldList__c where DisplayName__c= :i.simpfield];
                if(i.simpfunc != null)
                    sfunc=[select ID, FunctionList__c.DisplayName__c from functionList__c where DisplayName__c= :i.simpfunc];

              i.simpqClause.detailSrl__c = detailsrl2;
                i.simpqClause.ruleSimple_Id__c =rSimple.Id;
               
                
                if(scon != null)
                    i.simpqClause.ConditionList_ID__c= scon.ID;
                if(sfield != null)
                    i.simpqClause.FieldList_ID__c=sfield.ID;
                 if(sfunc != null)
                    i.simpqClause.FunctionList_ID__c=sfunc.ID;
                
                 detailsrl2++;
                upsert i.simpqClause;
            } 
    
    //for creation of aggregate qualifying clause
     

      for(InnerClass i:qInner){
                ConditionList__c con;
                FieldList__c field;
                aggregateFunction__c aa;
                functionList__c sfunc;  
                
                if(i.conditions != null)
                    con=[select ID, ConditionList__c.ConditionValue__c from ConditionList__c where ConditionValue__c=:i.conditions];
                if(i.fieldlist != null)
                    field=[select ID, FieldList__c.DisplayName__c from FieldList__c where DisplayName__c= :i.fieldlist];
                if(i.aggregates != null)
                    aa=[select ID,aggregateFunction__c.functionName__c from aggregateFunction__c  where functionName__c = :i.aggregates];
                if(i.funclist != null)
                    sfunc=[select ID, FunctionList__c.DisplayName__c from FunctionList__c where DisplayName__c= :i.funclist];

                i.qClause.detailSrl__c = detailsrl2;
                i.qClause.ruleSimple_Id__c =rSimple.Id;
              
                
                if(con != null)
                    i.qClause.ConditionList_ID__c= con.ID;
                if(field != null)
                    i.qClause.FieldList_ID__c=field.ID;
                if(aa != null)
                   i.qClause.aggregateFunctions_Id__c=aa.ID;
                if(sfunc != null)
                   i.qClause.FunctionList_ID__c=sfunc.ID;
          
                   detailsrl2++;
                upsert i.qClause;
            } 
            
            
     
        PageReference  pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RuleList');
        return pageRef;
     
    }
    }


    
    public pagereference a()
{

PageReference  pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RuleList');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);

        return pageRef;
        
 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This is a very large amount of code. Can you [edit] your post to show only the code elements that are related to this problem?

Comment: minimized the code to the problem context